# In Swift, how do I make a class's array of objects only accessible as an entire array?

Tags: swift

I have a pattern that I want developers to be able to access my classes, due to using property observers. In the examples below, I have property observer on B.a and A.str, below, so if developers try modify B.a.str directly, only the str property observer is fired. So I want to limit access to B.a to only setting and getting the entire array, making modifications have to happen outside of access to B directly (i.e., you'll see below). I have been reading a lot of Apple docs on Swift 4+, and I can't figure it out. Example below:

```
class A
{
 let str: String? = "Hello!"
 ...
}

class B
{
 var a: [A]()
 ...
}
```

I don't want users to use this set of classes like this:

```
let b: B = B()

B.a.str? = "NewValue"
```

How do I make "a" accessible only by this pattern:

```
let a_ref = b.a
a_ref.str? = "NewValue"
b.a = a_ref
```

Comment: by assigning `a_ref = b.a`, then calling `a_ref.str? = ""` you're making the same function call as you would be if you just did `B.a.str? = ""`

Comment: They are the same. You won't be able to allow one and not the other

Comment: After learning more and experimenting, this is absolutely achievable using subscript overloads and keeping the arrays private in the derived class. This way, member access to arrays can be completely controlled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you want to have this pattern and I am not sure if it's a good idea to use it. Anyway, you can achieve what you want by simply returning a copy of `a` when you use the getter that `B` provides.

```
class A {
    var str: String?

    init(str: String? = "Hello") {
        self.str = str
    }

    func copy() -> A {
        return A(str: str)
    }
}

class B {

    private var _a = A()
    var a: A {
        get { return _a.copy() }
        set { _a = newValue }
    }    

    init() { }
}
```

Now you can test it with the following code:

```
// First Attempt (Direct)

let b: B = B()
b.a.str = "NewValue"
print(b.a.str) // Prints "Hello"

// Second Attempt (via Reference)

let a_ref = b.a
a_ref.str = "NewValue"
b.a = a_ref
print(b.a.str) // Prints "NewValue
```

Comment: This is similar to what I was suspecting, like using getValue and setValue (and not getters / setters). There is a very good reason for this. I have property observers on B.a that do not trigger when B.a.str is modified, and I do not want to go into every super class to extend every type used with property observers as that would be terribly slow. The property observers I'm using on B are critical for realtime pre-computation and rapid tree traversal output. There wasn't any language constructs that stuck out for me to get around array property observers not firing on access.

Comment: See this Apple documentation on, "The Role of Mutation in Safety," https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10:

"One of the primary reasons to choose value types over reference types is the ability to more easily reason about your code. If you always get a unique, copied instance, you can trust that no other part of your app is changing the data under the covers. This is especially helpful in multi-threaded environments where a different thread could alter your data out from under you. This can create nasty bugs that are extremely hard to debug."